# how to pass parameter from one page function to another page class function in Javascript / Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I want to pass parameter from my `app.js` page to another page `User.js` which contain class function but all I am getting is `undefined` value. I am trying to pass selected choice from the inqurier but its not getting passed.

### User.js

```
class User{
  setUser(name){
    let userThing= fname(name);
    ...
    ...
    return userThing
  }

  getUser(){
    ...
    ...
    return
  }
}

module.exports.User=User;
```

### app.js

```
const { Command } = require("@oclif/command");
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const config = require("./User.js");

class RegionCommand extends Command {
 async run(){
   inquirer
   .prompt({
      type: "list",
      name: "test",
      message: " Select Nickname: ",
      default: false,
      choices: ["Tom", "Jerry"],
      })
      .then((answers) => {
        var selectedName=answers.test;
        // var nameDetails= this.config.User.setUser(selectedName); I tried this method too but still not working.
        var nameDetails= config.User.setUser(selectedName);
      });
 }
}
```

how can I pass my inqurier value app.js to user.js ?

Comment: I don't think you really understand how classes work.

Comment: ok @yainspan so how it work ?  I am really got stuck here

Comment: You should do some research into how JS classes work, and figure out how you want to use them to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: yes @yainspan I have to learn more i guess

Comment: You never stop learning :)

Comment: yeah :) @yainspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call a normal function like a static function. You first need to make a class instance!

```js
const { Command } = require("@oclif/command");
const inquirer = require("inquirer");
const { User } = require("./User.js");

class RegionCommand extends Command {
 async run(){
   inquirer
   .prompt({
      type: "list",
      name: "test",
      message: " Select Nickname: ",
      default: false,
      choices: ["Tom", "Jerry"],
      })
      .then((answers) => {
        var selectedName=answers.test;
        const user = new User(); // create an instance of the class "User"
        var nameDetails= user.setUser(selectedName);
      });
 }
}
```

Comment: @Aakash, maybe just add `static` before `setUser` in the User Class, call the function like `User.setUser()`